# How to get week dates from a given week no in C#

Tags: c#, php, datetime

I have PHP code that I need to convert into C#. Basically it calculates 5 dates of a given week.
The PHP code is as below:

```
    $period_week_start = new DateTime();
    $monday = $period_week_start->setISODate(2016, 36)->format('Ymd');
    $tuesday = $period_week_start->modify('+1 days')->format('Ymd');
```

**Output**

```
20160815
20160816
```

The C# code I am using is below:

```
 var monday = DateTime.Today.AddDays(-(int)DateTime.Today.DayOfWeek + (int)DayOfWeek.Monday).ToString("yyyyMMdd");
 var tuesday = DateTime.Today.AddDays(-(int)DateTime.Today.DayOfWeek + (int)DayOfWeek.Tuesday).ToString("yyyyMMdd");
```

**Output**

```
20160815
20160816
```

This does give me desired output but I need a way to pass a "**Week NO**" so I can get the dates of the given week.

To get the week no I use the following code:

```
 var currentCulture = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture;
 var weekNo = currentCulture.Calendar.GetWeekOfYear(DateTime.Now,
            currentCulture.DateTimeFormat.CalendarWeekRule, currentCulture.DateTimeFormat.FirstDayOfWeek);
```

Thank you

Comment: what is the question buddy?? can you please be more clear .

Comment: This question is very unclear. You have already shown code that will, given an arbitrary `DateTime` value, emit other `DateTime` values for specific days of the same week. You also have already shown code that will identify the "week of year" value for an arbitrary date. Why do you need to pass `weekNo` to anything? What specifically are you having trouble with?

Comment: Thanks @PeterDuniho my question is how to get these dates for a specific week (e.g week 34 or week 35). The current logic only gives me the "current" week's  monday, tuesday.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
public static DateTime[] WeekDaysFromWeekNo(int Year, int WeekNumber)
{
    DateTime start = new DateTime(Year, 1, 1).AddDays(7 * WeekNumber);
    start = start.AddDays(-((int)start.DayOfWeek));
    return Enumerable.Range(1, 7).Select(num => start.AddDays(num)).ToArray();
}
```

you can change the range to get say Monday to Friday and so on forth and format the dates the way you want it.